# Why is assignment of 0 or nullptr to std::string allowed, even when it results in a straight forward runtime exception?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, stdstring, nullptr

```
std::string s = 0;  // = nullptr ---> throws `std::logic_error`
```

Above statement results in segmentation fault. Why is it allowed?
[At least the constructor overload of `nullptr` should have been `=delete`, isn't it?]

Comment: _"[...] throws `std::logic_error`"_ - This attempted initialization never throws, it always results in UB.

Comment: @dfri "never does X" and "always UB" are mutually exclusive. UB can have any behaviour and thus there is nothing that could never happen.

Comment: @eerorika Yes you are right, of course (here be demons flying out of our noses); but I hope my main point to emphasize on the fact that this is UB rather than this seemingly throwing in a well-defined manner was not lost to anyone.

Comment: The question is a bit misleading.  The `std::string s = nullptr;` is not allowed.  C++ often does not prevent you from doing something that is not allowed at compile time, nor does it (typically) check for the not allowed thing at run time.  C++ is not a nanny language, it presumes the source code is valid.

Comment: @Eljay, you may want to revise your opinion. With C++23, it's proposed to prevent `string s = nullptr;` See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72881042). It's always good to have features which fix trivial errors at compile time to avoid waste of efforts.

Comment: @iammilind • That'll be a nice improvement to C++.  Will it also prevent `char const* p = nullptr; std::string s = p;`?

Comment: @Eljay, No, that's not prevented for obvious reasons. :-) From the [link](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2166r1.html) in my answer, a very similar example as yours is cited in **Further Discourse** to emphasize that this improvement is not intended to remove the regular runtime null-checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, the constructor to a `const char*` is called due to the way overload resolution works.

And if that pointer is `nullptr` then the standard library attempts to dereference a null pointer value with undefined results.

`std::string` is already hideously bloated. My guess is that nobody has managed to convince the C++ standards committee of the merits of having a `std::string(std::nullptr_t)` constructor.

Comment: I think they have a good reason: such a constructor would only catch sillynesses as written in the OP, but it wouldn't catch assignments of null pointer values of type `const char*`.

Answer (score 2):

For upcoming C++23, it's already proposed to prevent explicit `nullptr/NULL/0` assignment to `std::string` and `std::string_view`.

[A Proposal to Prohibit `std::basic_string` and `std::basic_string_view` construction from `nullptr`.](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2166r1.html)

---

Though one may not use `string s = nullptr` in practice, it may get triggered sometimes unintentionally in a generic code. e.g.

```
template<typename T>
struct X {
  ...
  T t = 0;
  ...
};

X<int> xi; // ok
X<float> xf; // ok
X<string> xs; // c++20 = runtime assert? --- c++23 = compiler error!
```